# Why am I getting a parse error on input `|'

Tags: haskell

```
takeEveryNth :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
takeEveryNth g destination
   | [] destination == []
   | otherwise = [g !! destination] ++ takeEveryNth (drop (destination+1) g) destination
```

I keep getting the error message in the title for line 4 of this code ( | otherwise =…)
I have tried changing the indentation but can't figure why I am getting this error

Comment: The `[] destination` makes no sense. Furthermore it is `... = ...`, not `... == ...`

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because your first guard expression does not evaluate to a boolean expression where `=` follows.

I think this should do it:

```
takeEveryNth :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
takeEveryNth g destination
   | length g <= destination = []
   | otherwise = [g !! destination] ++ takeEveryNth (drop (destination+1) g) destination
```

#### [Demo](https://repl.it/repls/DodgerblueHonoredInitializationfile)

Test:

```
takeEveryNth [1..10] 2
```

Produces:

```
[3,6,9]
```

and

```
takeEveryNth [1..10] 1
```

Produces:

```
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

Comment: Great thank you. Any idea why I was getting the error in the first place though?

Comment: I believe guard expressions should evaluate to booleans, so your first guard was not proper

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this does not work is because the parser expects a *singe* `=`, not a `==` for a guard. That being said, you use guards as if they are patterns. Guards work with expressions that have type `Bool`. So a guard like `| [] destination = ...` makes no sense.

You likely want to implement something like:

```
takeEveryNth :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
takeEveryNth [] _ = []
takeEveryNth g destination = [g !! destination] ++ takeEveryNth (drop (destination+1) g) destination
```

This however is still not sufficient, since if the list `g` contains less than `n` elements, the `g !! destination` will error. Furthermore wrapping the values in a singleton list is not necessary, you can use the "cons" function `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. You can make use of `drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]` to safely split at a given element, and then perform pattern matching, for example in a *pattern guard* on that result:

```
takeEveryNth :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
takeEveryNth g n
    | (x:xs) <- drop (n-1) g = x : takeEveryNth xs n
    | otherwise = []
```

Comment: I'm still learning Haskell from a book, and it did not discuss pattern guards, so thank you for teaching me something new!